# Custom date range sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, typescript

I am going though a project an attempting to remove unnecessary 3rd party dependencies in places where native JS accomplishes the job.  We use Underscore's `_.sortBy` to sort an array of dates, but for some reason I can't quite duplicate the exact sort order yet.

The data comes back unsorted and looks like this:

```
{
    "title": "February 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-02-01T10:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-03-01T09:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of February 28 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-02-28T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-03-06T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "March 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-03-01T10:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-04-01T07:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of March 06 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-03-06T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-03-13T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of March 13 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-03-13T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-03-20T03:59:59.000Z"
  },
```

Basically it needs just standard date sorting, except the "week of..." ranges should  appear *before* the entire month range.

This is how it is done currently using Underscore & MomentJS (also using Typescript), this correctly sorts it exactly how we want:

```
_.sortBy(dateRanges, (range: IDateRange) => {
  if (moment(range.endTime).diff(range.startTime, "days") > 7) {
    return range.endTime;
  } else {
    return range.startTime;
  }
});
```

I am attempting to duplicate that exact output, but without using Underscore or MomentJS.  Here's what I have so far:

```
dateRanges.sort((r1: IDateRange, r2: IDateRange) => {
  //604800000 milliseconds in 1 week
  //easier to hard code number this than do all the math on each iteration here
  const isWholeMonth = r1.endTime.getTime() - r1.startTime.getTime() > 604800000;

  if (isWholeMonth) {
    if (r1.endTime > r2.endTime) {
      return 1;
    } else if (r1.endTime < r2.endTime) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  } else {
    //Make the week listings for a month appear before the entire month listings
    if (r1.startTime > r2.startTime) {
      return 1;
    } else if (r1.startTime < r2.startTime) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
});
```

It's not entirely sorting correctly yet, but I can't quite figure out why. Here's a working  demo that outputs both of those to the console so the
http://codepen.io/chrismbarr/pen/KWOaaE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscore's `_sortBy` works differently than native `sort`. You need to check and compare different things, depending on if you have the `'week'` present in the title or not (or check startTime and endTime, up to you):

```
interface IDateRange {
    title: string;
    startTime: Date;
    endTime: Date;
}

const dateRanges: IDateRange[] = [
  {
    "title": "February 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-02-01T10:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-03-01T09:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of February 28 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-02-28T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-03-06T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "March 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-03-01T10:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-04-01T07:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of March 06 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-03-06T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-03-13T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of March 13 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-03-13T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-03-20T03:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "October 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-10-01T08:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-11-01T07:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of October 02 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-10-02T04:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-10-09T03:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of October 30 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-10-30T04:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-11-06T03:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "November 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-11-01T08:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-12-01T09:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of November 13 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-11-13T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-11-20T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of November 20 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-11-20T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-11-27T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of November 27 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-11-27T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-12-04T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "December 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-12-01T10:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2017-01-01T09:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of December 04 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-12-04T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-12-11T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of December 11 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-12-11T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2016-12-18T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of December 25 2016",
    "startTime": "2016-12-25T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2017-01-01T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "January 2017",
    "startTime": "2017-01-01T10:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2017-02-01T09:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of January 15 2017",
    "startTime": "2017-01-15T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2017-01-22T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of January 29 2017",
    "startTime": "2017-01-29T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2017-02-05T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "February 2017",
    "startTime": "2017-02-01T10:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2017-03-01T09:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of February 05 2017",
    "startTime": "2017-02-05T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2017-02-12T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of February 12 2017",
    "startTime": "2017-02-12T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2017-02-19T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "March 2017",
    "startTime": "2017-03-01T10:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2017-04-01T07:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of March 05 2017",
    "startTime": "2017-03-05T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2017-03-12T04:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of March 12 2017",
    "startTime": "2017-03-12T05:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2017-03-19T03:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of March 19 2017",
    "startTime": "2017-03-19T04:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2017-03-26T03:59:59.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Week of March 26 2017",
    "startTime": "2017-03-26T04:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2017-04-02T03:59:59.000Z"
  }
];

////==============================

console.clear();

//Convert to real data objects...
for (const range of dateRanges) {
  range.startTime = moment(range.startTime).utc().toDate();
  range.endTime = moment(range.endTime).utc().toDate();
}


//OLD
const librarySort = _.sortBy(dateRanges, (range: IDateRange) => {
  if (moment(range.endTime).diff(range.startTime, "days") > 7) {
    return range.endTime;
  } else {
    return range.startTime;
  }
});

//NEW - changes made here
const nativeSort = dateRanges.sort((r1: IDateRange, r2: IDateRange) => {
  let firstPartToCompare;
  let secondPartToCompare;

  if(r1.title.indexOf('eek') > -1) {
    firstPartToCompare = r1.startTime;
  } else {
    firstPartToCompare = r1.endTime;
  }

  if(r2.title.indexOf('eek') > -1) {
    secondPartToCompare = r2.startTime;
  } else {
    secondPartToCompare = r2.endTime;
  }

  if (firstPartToCompare > secondPartToCompare) {
    return 1;
  } else if (firstPartToCompare < secondPartToCompare) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});

console.info("CORRECT order - old way")
console.table(librarySort);

console.info("ATTEMPT to duplicate - new way")
console.table(nativeSort);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWVrwB

Comment: Using string comparison with `>` which will be lexicographical is a bad idea for dates. Use `.valueOf()` to get the numeric Epoch Time value and sort by that. Be sure to convert to UTC first.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick.  I knew I was miossing something simple.  Here's the basics of what I changed to get it to go off of the dates instead of the presence of the word "week":

`const r1IsWholeMonth = r1.endTime.getTime() - r1.startTime.getTime() > 604800000;

const firstPartToCompare = r1IsWholeMonth ? r1.endTime : r1.startTime;`

Comment: @ChrisBarr Not a problem, it was quite late for me, so I wanted to keep it simple. Comparing time differences is also good way to go with, also take Aluan's comment into account.